# Detecting if div has certain class that was added with a click (without refreshing)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am detecting clicks on a div without a certain class (class="off") and at the end of the function, a cookie is set that triggers some php code to add the class "off" after refreshing the page, and so after clicking and refreshing the page, the action of the function no longer works on that specific div any more. All good so far...

The problem I am having is that I want for the function to stop working on any div that has been clicked, without having to refresh the page. I tried adding the class using .addClass at the end of the function, but even though now when a div is clicked it does work and add the "off" class, but if clicked again, the function still works on the div, and I have the feeling it isn't detecting for changes to the original html code.

How can I make it stop working after one click?

```
$('#example').not('.off').click(function() {
// do stuff
$('#example').addClass('off');
}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: You'll need to unbind the click handler on elements which have had the 'off' class added, since the click handler is initial bound to those elements when they don't have `.off` and `.click()` doesn't affect live changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The handler once bound on an element cannot be removed just by removing the class. You need to unbind the handler as well

```
$('#example').not('.off').on('click', function() {
    // do stuff
    $('#example').addClass('off');
    //remove the event handler
    $('#example').off('click');
}
```

Another solution would be that You can check if the div already has the class by

```
if($('#example').hasClass("off"))
{
    return;
}
```

This is an alternate solution. I would call this a quickfix.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` instead.

```
$('#example').not('.off').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('off');
});
```

Or if you want to trigger an event once use `one`

```
$('#example').one('click', function() {
    // this code will be executed once per element
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the addclass is added only if certain other things happen within the function, which makes the $this not apply (it goes through other functions). And the problem isn't that the 'off' isn't added, it's that the function doesn't detect that the div has a new class called "off"

Answer (score 0):

How about not using additional class and simple removing an event handler with [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$('#example').click(function() {
  $(this).off('click');
});
```